# using mongo aggregation how to get the null month value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying this mongo aggregation get the last four months of data and calculate the each month of avarage value. I got the output, but how to get null month of value, ex: 3 months  data are there one month data are not inserted for example April month value not inserted but to display "April":0?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
            { $match: {
                CREATE_DATE: {
                    $lte:new Date(),
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
                        Date().getDate()-120)
                    )
                }
            } },
            { $group: {
                _id:{ 
                    month: { $month: "$CREATE_DATE" },
                    year: { $year: "$CREATE_DATE" }
                },
                avgofozone:{$avg:"$OZONE"}
            } },
            { $sort:{ "year": -1 } },
            { $project: {
                year: '$_id.year',
                avgofozone: '$avgofozone',
                month: '$_id.month',_id:0
            } },
            {
        $addFields: { 
            result: { 
                $let: {
                    vars: { "months": [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
         "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],


                        arr: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } }, 
                    in: {
                        "k" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$months" , { $subtract: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr.v" , 2 ] }, 1 ] } ] }, // the key will be the month index translated into the string representation
                        "v" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr.v" , 1 ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$year", // group by year
            result: { $push: "$result" },
        }
    }, {
        $addFields: {
            "result": { $arrayToObject: "$result" },
        }
    }, {
        $addFields: {
            "result.year": "$_id"
        }
    }, {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$result"
        }
    }

      ]
       )
```

Actual Output:

```
{
"Mar" : 55.6,
"Jan" : 31.265,
"Feb" : 31.265, 
"year" : 2018
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
 "Mar" : 55.6,
 "Jan" : 31.265,
 "Feb" : 31.265,
 "Apr" :0
 "year" : 2018,
}
```

Comment: If you effectively mean `["March","May"]` in your output needs to be `["March", "April", "May"]` then that really is not a wise track to go on. The database is returning the results which are "actually there". Returning something that "isn't there" involves munging the results to create fake "blank data". Do this on the client side instead.

Comment: As for within the context of the question, nobody is going to try to decipher this tangle of code with no data and no reproducible case. You have been pointed at the basic requirement of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on several occasions. You really need to follow the format as described there.